# Setting up a custom Value in Multi select Parameter - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, multi-select, ssrs-2008-r2

How can we set a default value to `" "` in Multi select control of SSRS.

For example: I have data something like,

```
" ","A","B","C"
```

SQL Query something like below by which I'm binding my Multi select parameter control.

```
SELECT Code,[Description] FROM MyTable UNION SELECT ' ' Code ,'ALL' [Description] ORDER BY Code
```

So, I want to set a default selected value as `" "` in Multi select Parameter.

**Currently it looks like below,**

[image: Currently it looks like this]

**I want something like below - Set All by default,**

[image]

**Note:** *I know that we can set `(Selecte All)` as by default. But I don't want to do that.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried defining the default value of the parameter in SSRS?

Looking at your question above I assume your Parameter is set up to use values from the query as follows

[image]

You then need to specify the default value.  While this looks blank I have actually set the Value to be a single space (in the red circle)

[image]

Now when you run the report the parameter defaults to "ALL'

[image]

Comment: thanks dude, its working fine. Actually I had already tried by setting default value as `=" "` - but was not working. still I'm not getting what's difference between `=" "` and single space. btw thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  Sometimes it's just a case of playing with things until they work out for you.